# forEach Loop not returning Array

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js, foreach, ejs

So, i seem to be having a problem with returning a value from my forEach MYSQL query loop in Node JS and then inserting this into an ejs template. Currently, these are my pieces of code:

app.js GET Request

```
app.get("/admin/stock", function(req, res) {
db.query("SELECT * FROM stock", function (err, stock) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error with showing SQL")
    } else {
        stock.forEach(function (stock) {
                db.query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE productID = " + 
stock.stock_productID, function (err, product) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error");
                    }
                    else {
                        stock.stock_productID = product[0].productName
                    }

                });
                db.query("SELECT * FROM currency WHERE currencyID = " + 
stock.stock_currencyID, function (err, currency) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error");
                    }
                    else {
                        stock.stock_currencyID = currency[0].currencyName
                    }

                });
                db.query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customerID = " + 
    stock.stock_customerID, function (err, customer) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error");
                    }
                    else {
                        stock.stock_customerID = 
    customer[0].customerBusiness;
                        console.log(stock);
                    }
                })
        });
    }
    console.log(stock);
    res.render("admin/stock", {stock:stock, userFName: req.user[1]})
})
});
```

Stock Page EJS

```
        <table class="generalTable">
            <tr>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Currency</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
                <th>Date Bought</th>
                <th>Bought From</th>
            </tr>
            <% stock.forEach(function(stock){ %>
            <tr>
                <td><%=stock.stock_productID%></td>
                <td><%=stock.quantityStockCurrent%></td>
                <td><%=stock.stock_currencyID%></td>
                <td><%=stock.priceBought%></td>
                <td><%=stock.boughtDate%></td>
                <td><%=stock.stock_customerID%></td>
            </tr>
            <% }) %>
        </table>
```

The First console.log of stock shows the replaced values, the second however, shows the original array values, and therefore the page is loaded in with the original values (IDs etc, instead of names).

How do I send the inner/edited array to the res.render instead of the original array?

Many Thanks,
Brad

EDIT//////

By using JOINs, the output was correct

Comment: You really need to learn how `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` work in SQL. Your code is the most inefficient way of retrieving information from a relational database. There is no use fixing this, please read about joins and rewrite your query.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I was being foolish in forgetting about JOINs!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the database queries have not yet returned when you already render the stock object.

Remember, nodejs is asynchronous. You have to wait for all DB queries to come back before rendering the result.

I did have a similar problem when I first learned about nodejs: [JavaScript nodejs mysql with queries in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068290/javascript-nodejs-mysql-with-queries-in-a-loop)

Comment: Thanks for the information, i've tried working it similar to how you did and i just get errors, and cant get it to call the res.render

Comment: @SomeGenuineGuy write a new question on StackOverflow then if you get stuck. Don't forget to put in all stack traces and other relevant info. State what you tried and what you think. If you want to thank me, upvote this post!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that javascript is asynchronous and that Javascript doesn't have a block scope, which means that you render file before the loop complete so you should use simple for loop for this.

you should replace your code with this :-

```
app.get("/admin/stock", function(req, res) {
    db.query("SELECT * FROM stock", function (err, stocks) {
         var stock = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stocks));
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error with showing SQL")
        } else {
            for(var i = 0 ; i< stock.length; i++) {
                db.query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE productID = " +
                    stock[i].stock_productID, function (err, product) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error");
                    }
                    else {
                        stock[i].stock_productID = product[0].productName
                    }   

                });
                db.query("SELECT * FROM currency WHERE currencyID = " +
                    stock[i].stock_currencyID, function (err, currency) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error");
                    }
                    else {
                        stock[i].stock_currencyID = currency[0].currencyName
                    }

                });
                db.query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customerID = " +
                    stock[i].stock_customerID, function (err, customer) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error");
                    }
                    else {
                        stock[i].stock_customerID =
                            customer[0].customerBusiness;
                        console.log(stock);
                    }
                });
                if(i === stock.length-1){
                    console.log(stock);
                    res.render("admin/stock", {stock:stock, userFName: req.user[1]})
                }
            };



        }

    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I now get this error:

    TypeError: Cannot set property 'stock_productID' of undefined

Why would this be?

Comment: i think the stock which you get from stock table is empty thats ehy you get TypeError so you should console stock first to know what stock actually contain

Comment: Stock is not empty once the query is finalised, how do I only run the for loop after the stock table is fully queried? Thanks

Comment: i edit the code  try it out if you get similar problem send me the data which you get after consoling stock

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property 'stock_productID' of undefined
    at Query._callback app.js:292:50) -- This Equates to line 13 in your code snippet above

Comment: [ RowDataPacket {
    stockID: 1,
    quantityStockBought: 100,
    quantityStockCurrent: 50,
    priceBought: 30,
    stock_customerID: 2,
    stock_currencyID: 2,
    stock_productID: 1,
    boughtDate: 2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z },
  RowDataPacket {
    stockID: 2,
    quantityStockBought: 100,
    quantityStockCurrent: 0,
    priceBought: 40,
    stock_customerID: 1,
    stock_currencyID: 1,
    stock_productID: 2,
    boughtDate: 2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z },

And this is the console.log of stock when put on line 6

Comment: can you send me the part of console that you get by consoling stock

Answer (score 0):

You can use async.map for executing query in loop.

```
function getResults(id,cb){
  db.query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE productID = " +
            id.stock_productID, function (err, product) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error");
            }
            else {
                id.stock_productID = product[0].productName
            }   

        });  
}
async.mapLimit(stock, 5, function(id, callback) {
   getResults(id, function (err, res) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    callback(null, res);
   })
}, function(err, results) {
// results is an array of names
});
```